# Creating stacked image parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I'm attempting to create a parallax effect that will take 4 images and as you scroll a bit down the page the 4 images begin to stack on top of each other. Here is a visual example of this burger coming together on [Smokey Bones Website](http://smokeybones.com/). This is a much more complex example than I need just trying to give some visual insight. I am fairly well versed in Javascript, Jquery, and such and just need some ideas how to start this process regarding the mathematical portion or any examples.

Comment: Could you just use some PNG files with transparent backgrounds, and place them in a DIV using absolute positioning?  Adjust the positions manually on Scroll event.

Comment: @RyanGriggs That is about as far as I got with my logic haha. any simple example that could be thrown together to illusrate this?

Comment: @reblace its been several years since calculus haha. any simple example that could be thrown together to illusrate this function?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the basic idea: http://jsfiddle.net/reblace/z8P56/1

I'm just using a linear function for the image offset:

```
$("#img1").css({top: (scroll)*100 + 'px' });
```

Obviously, you can get way more complex with this. Ideally you should get stuff like the page height from the page itself and not just hardcode it.

Another thing to note is that the real parallax formula is more complex and involves trigonometry and the relative distances and angle of the objects being drawn from the view position. The linear function I use in the example is a simplification that you can probably get away with for the purposes of the Web.

Basically, you want to think of it in terms of a domain of values and a range of values... ie. the scroll position is from 0 to 5000px, and the image I want to have go from 0 to 100px. So if the domain is [0, 5000] and the range is [0, 100], I'd map the domain to a range from 0 to 1 and then scale it up to go from 0 to 100, ie. imagePos = (scrollPos/5000)*100

If I instead wanted to map the scroll position of 0-5000 to an image position of 10-50, I'd have to scale and shift the previous formula, ie. imagePos = (scrollPos/5000)*40 + 10

You could reverse the scrolling (from 50 to 10) by inverting the 0-1 scale before scaling and shifting, ie. imagePos = (1 - (scrollPos/5000))*40 + 10

I think you can probably get the effect you want by playing around with these examples.

**Update:** Here's a slightly more complex Fiddle with comments that uses a more robust method for calculating the correct scroll range and window height. Also, this one demonstrates the inverted scrolling of the images: http://jsfiddle.net/reblace/z8P56/4.

Comment: wow you are amazing thank you! I'm going to read this over and give it a try!

Comment: finally got around to implementing this and works perfectly just one LAST quick question, How would i go about reaching the collapsed images before the full of the window, say about 500px short of the end of the document?